# Precision plotting in time axis

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I have a trouble plotting data, I only want plot HH:MM:SS but the plot shows HH:MM:SS.sssss or HH:MM:SS.%f. Below i gonna detail what I did (matplotlib, numpy are already imported )

Method I

Loading files to plot

```
import datetime as dt
data=genfromtxt('27JAN12.K7O', delimiter=2*[4]+5*[2]+8*[7])
f245   = data[:, 7]
```

Generating array for time (1 data per second)

```
base = dt.datetime(2014,1,27,11,07,59)
time  = array([base + dt.timedelta(seconds=i) for i in range(len(data))])
plot(time,f245)
```

When i did this, i got this plot (with innecesary precision)

[image]

here i got time like 18:15:00.000000 (i just like 18:15:00)

Method II

The same way to load data, in this case only I took the time of the data and coverted in time string

```
t      =  data[:,1] #in decimals e.g. 18,5 represents 18:30:00
tstr   =  map(str, [dt.timedelta(seconds=x) for x in t])
time = []
for i in tstr:
    try:
        time.append(dt.datetime.strptime(i, "%H:%M:%S"))
    except ValueError:
        time.append(dt.datetime.strptime(i, "%H:%M:%S.%f"))
plot(time,f245)
```

[image]

In this case, i got time like 18:15:00.%f

So, how i could repair this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`plot_date`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date) to plot `datetime` objects using matplotlib.

You can use `matplotlib.dates.date2num` to convert the `datetime` objects into the matplotlib format.

Furthermore you can use `DateFormatter` objects to set the formatting of the x-axis tick labels.

I have now included a small example using generated data, hopefully this will explain everything for you.

```
import numpy as numpy

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import date2num, DateFormatter

import datetime as dt

base = dt.datetime(2014, 1, 27, 11, 7, 59)

x = [base + dt.timedelta(seconds=i) for i in range(10)]
y = [i**2 for i in range(10)]

x = date2num(x) # Convert datetime objects to the correct format for matplotlib.

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot_date(x, y) # Use plot_date rather than plot

# Set the xaxis major formatter as a DateFormatter object
# The string argument shows what format you want (HH:MM:SS)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))

# This simply makes them look pretty by setting them diagonal.
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot]

Comment: And for establish x limits i could do "xlim(dt.datetime(2014, 01, 27,18,00),dt.datetime(2014, 01, 27,18,30))"? I did this and it works but are there another form?